# Sumar tiempo en PHP array

Tags: php, html, sql

Estoy guardando la hora en la base de datos con un campo de tipo `time`. Estoy recorriendo un array de datos y deseo poder sumarlos.

Tengo el siguiente método:

```
 <?php sumaHoras = 0; ?>
 <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>

            $value_horario   = $row['total'];
            $parts           = explode(':', $value_horario);
            $resultado       = ($parts[0] + ($parts[1]/6) / 10 . PHP_EOL);
            $sumaHoras       = $sumaHoras + $resultado;
        } ?>
 <?php echo $sumaHoras; ?>
```

Si en mi Array `$row['total']` vienen 3 horas, la suma de esas `00:30:00` + `04:30:00` + `01:00:00` me da resultado de `1.50`. Me debería dar `7:00` o `07:00:00`.

He estado mirando algunos códigos pero ninguno me ha resultado.

Comment: cuales son los valores que traes desde la BD?

Comment: @MoteCL Es necesario el uso de `array`, solo deseas sumar 3 horas a una hora actual?

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el SQL que usas para obtener los datos?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Creo que lo recomendado es realizar la suma en segundos y luego convertir el total al formato deseado, de la siguiente manera:

```
$horasbd = [ '00:30:00', '01:00:00', '04:30:00'];

function sumarHoras($horas) {
    $total = 0;
    foreach($horas as $h) {
        $parts = explode(":", $h);
        $total += $parts[2] + $parts[1]*60 + $parts[0]*3600;        
    }   
    return gmdate("H:i:s", $total);
}

echo sumarHoras($horasbd);

//  06:00:00
```

Comment: Funciona muy bien gracias

Comment: Una consulta al sumar `25:00:00` hrs me muestra `01:00:00`

Comment: Porque lel formato de hora maxima es 24.

Answer (score 3):

segun lo que se entiende de tus necesidades y complementado con la ayuda de @Oswuell, si necesitas sumas varias horas diferente, lo puedes hacer asi:

```
$arrayHoras  = array($hora1, $hora2, $hora3);

sumarHoras($horasArray){
  $sumaHoras=0;
  for ($j = 0; $j < count($horasArray) 0; $j++ {

    $value_horario   = $horasArray[$j];
    $parts           = explode(':', $value_horario);
    $resultado      = ($parts[0] + ($parts[1]/6) / 10 . PHP_EOL);
    $sumaHoras = $sumaHoras + $resultado
  }
  return $resultado
}
sumarHoras($arrayHoras);
```

asi podrias sumar tantas horas como quisieras....

espero te sirva, nos cuentas!

Comment: realize un cambio en tu codigo, funciona pero en la suma hay un error. ya que al sumar `00:45:00 ` + `04:30:00 ` me da `5.25` y deberia ser `5:15`
Editare mi codigo agregando tu parte

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto, yo lo utilizo y me funciona perfecto

```
$value_horario   = "$hora1";
$parts           = explode(':', $value_horario);
$res_inicio      = ($parts[0] + ($parts[1]/6) / 10 . PHP_EOL);

$value_horario   = "$hora2";
$parts1_horario  = explode(':', $value_horario);
$res_termino     = ($parts1_horario[0] + ($parts1_horario[1]/6) / 10 . PHP_EOL);

$resultado = $res_inicio + $res_termino;
```

Primero tienes que eliminar los ":" para transformarlos a números enteros.

Comment: que ocurre cuando son mas de 2 horas? mirando sirve para sumar solo dos horas.

Comment: Seria genial si explicaras mejor tu respuesta...

Comment: A que te refieres con mas de 2 horas ? Explica entonces tu duda.

Comment: Pues si necesitas sumas mas horas, entonces crea una funcion con este codigo (si es funcional para lo que necesitas) a la cual le pasarias por parametro un array con todas las horas que ncesitas y con un ciclo vas formateando las horas y las vas sumando, si es eso lo que necesitas @MoteCL

Comment: La repuesta que te di funciona sumando o restante las horas.

Comment: @Oswuell puedo tomar tu codigo y modificarlo para una respuesta ? o prefieres que modifique tu respuesta con mi idea ?

Comment: Si dale no mas, la idea de la comunidad es ayudarse entre todos.

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente la solución más limpia y elegante sea hacer la suma en el propio código SQL y obtener directamente el resultado:

```
SELECT
  SEC_TO_TIME(
    SUM(
      TIME_TO_SEC(total)
    )
  ) suma
FROM tabla;
```

Comienzo convirtiendo los campos `TIME` en segundos (desde las `00:00:00`) mediante la función [`TIME_TO_SEC()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec). A la suma total de todos los registros le hago el cálculo inverso (convertir los segundos transcurridos desde las `00:00:00` a hora) mediante la función [`SEC_TO_TIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time).

A diferencia de la respuesta marcada como correcta, si la suma sobrepasa las 24 horas, el resultado será coherente en horas y no volverá a empezar desde 0.

Tu código PHP quedaría:

```
<?php
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['suma'];
```

Puedes ver un [ejemplo en línea aquí](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iHB5EehMSCatbFzBKXtCvE/0).

Answer (score 0):

Yo suelo utilizar el objeto DateTime() y crear una fecha cualquiera seteando la hora que me interesa, luego con la función "modify" aumento la hora y la extraigo con "format".

En este ejemplo solo utilizo horas pero puedes restar fechas completas, minutos y lo que quieras de una forma bastante sencilla sin cálculos complejos.

```
$hora = '13:00';
$fecha = new DateTime('2018-01-24 '.$hora);

$fecha->modify("+1 hour");

$nuevaHora = $fecha->format('H').':00';

echo $nuevaHora;  // Muestra 14:00 y lo guardas o gestionas como necesites
```

Puedes combinar el formato como te interese, crear dos fechas si ves que puede incrementar o decrementar más de 24h y luego restarlas para ver la diferencia de horas, etc.

Es interesante consultar la documentación oficial ya que viene perfectamente explicado:

http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php

http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.modify.php